# How to ask another question in one question with rank

Tags: sql

I want to show it in the first output if the first rank equals 1 in my database

```
SELECT id, name,password,oldname,number,
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY oldname="mxmx" DESC),
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY number DESC)
as "Rank1"
 FROM account
```

For example like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/356JK.png)

please guide me to reach a conclusion

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products, what are you really using? Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are really using.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to supply expected results, use a markdown table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first-ranked items to appear first in the results, use:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    password,
    oldname,
    number,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY oldname="mxmx" DESC),
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number DESC) AS "Rank1"
FROM account
ORDER BY 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY oldname="mxmx" DESC)
```

Alternatively, you could wrap your original query inside a `SELECT * FROM (...) table_alias ORDER BY rank_alias` if you prefer. (Though you should select the actual columns you need -- I write the `*` for brevity only)

PS. Additionally, I found the order of the RANK's themselves returns the results ordered "last-RANK-first", for MySQL 8 at least.  Though I can't find a reference that would guarantee this behaviour, your query would be:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    password,
    oldname,
    number,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number DESC) AS "Rank1",
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY oldname="mxmx" DESC)
FROM account
```